# Python 2.7: Adding all elements of multiple arrays together

Tags: python, arrays, image, for-loop

I'm reading image files from a list with a variable number of objects.

How can I add the arrays from each file to each other?

Here's an example adding only two arrays:

```
imageArray= [sum(x,y) for x,y in zip(io.imread(list[1]),io.imread(list[2]))]
```

I want to extend this to be able to add a variable number of arrays.

I have tried the following, without avail:

```
for x in filelist:
    imageArray = [sum(y) for y in itertools.izip(io.imread(x))]
```

Which yields the error:
`TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data`

Any help would be much appreciated!

***Edit***

I have been able to read all the images into array using part of unutbu's answer below:

```
im =  map(SNIO.imread,filelist)
```

From here, I wish to add all the resulting arrays together (element wise). The correct solution would reproduce the result from the following code:

```
imageArray = [x+y+z for x,y,z in zip(im[0],im[1],im[2])]
```

which works fine, but, as stated in the original question, I wish to do this with any number of arrays rather than specifying them as in the previous example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `io.imread` the same as `scipy.ndimage.io.imread`?
If so, then to add the arrays element-wise, use [np.add.reduce](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.io as SNIO
files = ...
arrs = map(SNIO.imread, files)
result = np.add.reduce(arrs)
```

This will be far faster than calling Python's `sum` function for each location in the arrays.

Comment: `io.imread` is `skimage.io.imread`, which I believe is the same as `scipy.ndimage.io.imread` Nevertheless, the solution is not working as expected. `map.SNIO.imread, files` is a good start, but `np.add reduce(arrs)` does not produce the result I want. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I believe `np.add.reduce(arrs)` should produce the result you are looking for -- provided the values in `arrs` do not cause an arithmetic overflow. Note also that if an RGB image has 8-bits per channel the values in each channel can range from 0-255. After summing the result may easily exceed 255. So the result must be rescaled before it can be viewed as an image -- if that is what you are doing... Can you post some example images and explain what you expect as the result?

Comment: that solved it! I think the issue was that the resulting values exceeded 255, as you said. Thanks!